# Uploading images for user avatar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Right now I use Gravatar for user avatars on my website.

I want to let users upload images to use as avatars from my website to gravatar so they don't have to visit gravatar if they choose not to, and I don't have to support multiple avatar methods.  I don't know how to accomplish this in ASP.NET MVC.

In Ruby on Rails they made it easy; you just install a plugin. But in ASP you write the whole code yourself.

- What do I need to know to get started?
- Is there a Gravatar API for this?
- Is there an ASP plugin with this feature?
- Is there an easy way to convert Ruby code to ASP?

Comment: Do you have anything started?  Please post what you have so far so that we can help you get on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Gravatar does not appear to have an easy service or interface to upload avatars from other websites - they expect you to go to their website directly.

You're likely going to have to scrape their website, and act as an HTTP client to simulate the user going through the actions themselves.  It's not trivial, but if you look through the Ruby code you should have a very good idea of what the general process is.